# How to convert searchTwitter results (from library(twitteR)) into a data.frame?

Tags: r, twitter, rodbc

I am working on saving twitter search results into a database (SQL Server) and am getting an error when I pull the search results from twitteR.

If I execute:

```
library(twitteR)
puppy <- as.data.frame(searchTwitter("puppy", session=getCurlHandle(),num=100))
```

I get an error of:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class structure("status", package = "twitteR") into a data.frame
```

This is important because in order to use RODBC to add this to a table using sqlSave it needs to be a data.frame. At least that's the error message I got:

```
Error in sqlSave(localSQLServer, puppy, tablename = "puppy_staging",  : 
  should be a data frame
```

So does anyone have any suggestions on how to coerce the list to a data.frame or how I can load the list through RODBC?

My final goal is to have a table that mirrors the structure of values returned by searchTwitter. Here is an example of what I am trying to retrieve and load:

```
library(twitteR)
puppy <- searchTwitter("puppy", session=getCurlHandle(),num=2)
str(puppy)

List of 2
 $ :Formal class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 10 slots
  .. ..@ text        : chr "beautifull and  kc reg Beagle Mix for rehomes: This little puppy is looking for a new loving family wh... http://bit.ly/9stN7V "| __truncated__
  .. ..@ favorited   : logi FALSE
  .. ..@ replyToSN   : chr(0) 
  .. ..@ created     : chr "Wed, 16 Jun 2010 19:04:03 +0000"
  .. ..@ truncated   : logi FALSE
  .. ..@ replyToSID  : num(0) 
  .. ..@ id          : num 1.63e+10
  .. ..@ replyToUID  : num(0) 
  .. ..@ statusSource: chr "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitterfeed.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;twitterfeed&lt;/a&gt;"
  .. ..@ screenName  : chr "puppy_ads"
 $ :Formal class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 10 slots
  .. ..@ text        : chr "the cutest puppy followed me on my walk, my grandma won't let me keep it. taking it to the pound sadface"
  .. ..@ favorited   : logi FALSE
  .. ..@ replyToSN   : chr(0) 
  .. ..@ created     : chr "Wed, 16 Jun 2010 19:04:01 +0000"
  .. ..@ truncated   : logi FALSE
  .. ..@ replyToSID  : num(0) 
  .. ..@ id          : num 1.63e+10
  .. ..@ replyToUID  : num(0) 
  .. ..@ statusSource: chr "&lt;a href=&quot;http://blackberry.com/twitter&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Twitter for BlackBerry®&lt;/a&gt;"
  .. ..@ screenName  : chr "iamsweaters"
```

So I think the data.frame of puppy should have column names like:

```
- text
- favorited
- replytoSN
- created
- truncated
- replytoSID
- id
- replytoUID
- statusSource
- screenName
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ldply(searchTwitter("#rstats", n=100), text)
```

twitteR returns an S4 class, so you need to either use one of its helper functions, or deal directly with its slots.  You can see the slots by using `unclass()`, for instance:

```
unclass(searchTwitter("#rstats", n=100)[[1]])
```

These slots can be accessed directly as I do above by using the related functions (from the twitteR help: ?statusSource):

> ```
>  text Returns the text of the status
>  favorited Returns the favorited information for the status
>  replyToSN Returns the replyToSN slot for this status
>  created Retrieves the creation time of this status
>  truncated Returns the truncated information for this status
>  replyToSID Returns the replyToSID slot for this status
>  id Returns the id of this status
>  replyToUID Returns the replyToUID slot for this status
>  statusSource Returns the status source for this status
> ```

As I mentioned, it's my understanding that you will have to specify each of these fields yourself in the output.  Here's an example using two of the fields:

```
> head(ldply(searchTwitter("#rstats", n=100), 
        function(x) data.frame(text=text(x), favorited=favorited(x))))
                                                                                                                                          text
1                                                     @statalgo how does that actually work? does it share mem between #rstats and postgresql?
2                                   @jaredlander Have you looked at PL/R? You can call #rstats from PostgreSQL: http://www.joeconway.com/plr/.
3   @CMastication I was hoping for a cool way to keep data in a DB and run the normal #rstats off that. Maybe a translator from R to SQL code.
4                     The distribution of online data usage: AT&amp;T has recently announced it will no longer http://goo.gl/fb/eTywd #rstat
5 @jaredlander not that I know of. Closest is sqldf package which allows #rstats and sqlite to share mem so transferring from DB to df is fast
6 @CMastication Can #rstats run on data in a DB?Not loading it in2 a dataframe or running SQL cmds but treating the DB as if it wr a dataframe
  favorited
1     FALSE
2     FALSE
3     FALSE
4     FALSE
5     FALSE
6     FALSE
```

You could turn this into a function if you intend on doing it frequently.

Comment: Shane, what library do I need to load for that? Is it plyr?

Comment: I see that it is plyr. It did convert the list to a data.frame. Now the 10 columns that get returned from searchTwitter are in a single column in the data.frame. How can I split them out?

Comment: Can you update your question?  I'm not sure what you want the final output to look like...

Comment: I updated my question, thank you for your suggestions. I'm going through them trying to get this to get this in the right structure.

Comment: @analyticsPierce: see my response.

Comment: Alright! I am able to create the data.frame. Thank you for your help and patience with me. I'm a database marketing guy just getting into R. One follow up question on this, the above solution does not work for columns that may come back with no value like replyToSN. Is there something I can add so it can be assigned? 

If I run:  head(ldply(searchTwitter("puppy", n=100), 
        function(x) data.frame(text=text(x), favorited=favorited(x), replyToSN=replyToSN(x))))

I get: Error in data.frame : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Let me know if this should be a new question.

Answer (score 18):

I use this code I found from http://blog.ouseful.info/2011/11/09/getting-started-with-twitter-analysis-in-r/ a while ago:

```
#get data
tws<-searchTwitter('#keyword',n=10)

#make data frame
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(tws, as.data.frame))

#write to csv file (or your RODBC code)
write.csv(df,file="twitterList.csv")
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but still, here is what I think is a ``modern'' version to solve this. Just use the function `twListToDf`

```
gvegayon <- getUser("gvegayon")
timeline <- userTimeline(gvegayon,n=400)
tl <- twListToDF(timeline)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It seems to me that this solution only works if you search and work with the tweets of a specific user?

Comment: Yes, this is not really a solution... at least not to this problem or the general use case of twitteR

Comment: I disagree. The problem was basically how to get a data.frame from a status object from twitteR. If you have a list of it, which is the case of the original question, then you just apply the function to each object in the list. HTH

Comment: Looks good to me. Works fine for multiple users: `twListToDF(lapply(c('@handle1','@handle2'), getUser))`

Answer (score 1):

For those that run into the same problem I did which was getting an error saying

```
Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

I simply changed the word text in

```
ldply(searchTwitter("#rstats", n=100), text)
```

to statusText, like so:

```
ldply(searchTwitter("#rstats", n=100), statusText)
```

Just a friendly heads-up :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice function to convert it into a DF.

```
TweetFrame<-function(searchTerm, maxTweets)
{
  tweetList<-searchTwitter(searchTerm,n=maxTweets)
  return(do.call("rbind",lapply(tweetList,as.data.frame)))
}
```

Use it as :

```
tweets <- TweetFrame(" ", n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `twitteR` package now includes a function `twListToDF` that will do this for you.

```
puppy_table <- twListToDF(puppy)
```