# r - convert the searchTwitter output to data frame?

Tags: r, list, twitter, dataframe, lapply

Hello everybody in Stackoverflow. 
I am a newbie R user, and having problem with lapply function.

Now I am using R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
running on Ubuntu server 12.04.2 LTS.

My problem is I can't use lapply function to convert the output from searchTwitter (in twitteR) to data frame.

I can gather the tweet into 'tweet' variable, but can't convert to the data frame.

My code:

```
require(twitteR) 
require(RJSONIO)
load('cred.Rdata')
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
tweet <- searchTwitter('bus')
tweet1 <- lapply(tweet, as.data.frame) //error here
df <- do.call("rbind",tweet1)
write.csv(df,file='oneearthquake.csv')
```

I got the error:

```
Error in data.frame(text= "(tweet text)")
    arguments imply differing number of rows: 1,0
```

I have tried on another Ubuntu server which running the same R version, it can run with out any warning. Could please tell me the way to solve this error?

Thank you in advance

Ploy

Comment: Have you tried [`twListToDF`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/twitteR/docs/twListToDF) or the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3056146/1036500)? They may be a bit dated though...

Comment: I tried and the error was the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
load('cred.Rdata')
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
rawtweets <- searchTwitter("bus")

df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(rawtweets, as.data.frame))
write.csv(df, file='oneearthquake.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
I tried it , but error was the same.

Comment: This worked for me